# a function with no return statement returns (react)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, function

react(javascript) beginner here, shoudn't a function without return statement give 'undefined' ? how about invoking another function inside a function still needs a return statement(did not find this information in other place)?

for example what is the reason that this code works with and without return statement and does not give 'undefined'?

```js
function TodoForm({ addTodo }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
   //for example this function does not have a return statement and still works
   // even if i put return statement it will still work 
   // like this return addTodo(value) ?
    addTodo(value);
    setValue('');
  }
  console.log(value);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Add Todo..."
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}

      />
    </form>
  )

}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some context - What did you expect to happen? Are you coming from a different language? I'm asking since I am not aware of a different behavior for return statements, unless I am misunderstanding the question :).

Comment: Functions can affect the external environment without having a `return` statement, which is what your function is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Functions don't have to return anything. In that case they would be considered as `void` type functions.

```js
const returnArgument = argument => {
 return argument;
};
console.log(returnArgument('foo')); // logs 'foo'

const voidFunction = argument => {
 returnArgument(argument);
};
console.log(voidFunction(argument)); // logs undefined

const doubleReturn = argument => {
 return returnArgument(argument);
};
console.log(doubleReturn('foo')); // logs 'foo'
```

However no matter if functions return something or they don't, doesn't mean that they can not make changes to some state or have any other widely defined `side-effects`.
If you would like to learn more about functions, pure functions and side-effects then I would suggest [this article](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript) as an entry point reelated to JavaScript.

So back to your case - even though your `handleSubmit` doesn't have a return statement, it performs few other operations which are considered `side-effects`:

1. it calls function `addTodo`, therefore making change to some outer state
2. it calls function `setValue`, making change to local state defined with `useState` hook

So that's why the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps confusing the definition of the `handleSubmit` function from the call to `e => {}`? Do note that `e => {}` **is** the `handleSubmit` function.

If the code you posted looks confusing perhaps it is better to rewrite it as follows which is exactly (almost) the same code:

```
function TodoForm({ addTodo }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   //for example this function does not have a return statement and still works
   // even if i put return statement it will still work 
   // like this return addTodo(value) ?
    addTodo(value);
    setValue('');
  }
  console.log(value);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Add Todo..."
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}

      />
    </form>
  )

}
```